# Asp net core 2.1 App-metrics and identityserver4

Tags: c#, identityserver4, metrics

I was looking for a way to use App.Metrics.AspNetCore.Tracking with IdentityServer4.  I want to be able to track the metrics for each endpoint that is hit, e.g. /connect/token
However, I can't get it to track these.  It is however tracking the endpoints that I have a controller for and displaying the metrics for those endpoints no problem, but doesn't track any of the identity server 4 endpoints.  How do I get this to track middleware endpoints?

Thanks in advance